# Jquery - Avoid empty inputs

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I'm doing a multi step form (form wizard) and I have splitted the form into 5 parts... so mi first div is like this:

```
<div class="data-1" style="display: block; ">
    <h3>Data</h3>
    <fieldset class="inputs">
    <ol>
      // 5 text inputs here
    </ol>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Via jquery I was trying to grab the 5 inputs of each div (the other divs has also checkboxes, radio buttons) by doing this

```
 $(".data-1 :input").val();
```

in order to know the value of the inputs of each div... but it seems that I have to iterate over div inputs.

Is there a way I can prevent any empty input? or is there a plugin that do this?

Comment: *"...but it seems that I have to iterate over div inputs."* Huh? `div` elements are not `input` elements.

Comment: over the inputs that are inside the div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at jQuery.Validate

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").validate();
  });
  </script>

<form id="myForm" method="post">
   <p>
     <label for="cname">Name</label>
     <input id="cname" name="name" size="25" class="required" minlength="2" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <label for="curl">URL</label>
     <input id="curl" name="url" size="25"  class="url" value="" />
   </p>
   <p>
     <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </p>
 </form>
```

Comment: At first sight it seems to validate the entire form... is there a way to validate parts of it?

Comment: your input attributes tells the validator which elements to validate and how to validate them. It works great and I really recommend  youto have a closer look at it! :)

Comment: Well... I'll give it a try, because I'm not sure if I can do something like this:  $(".datos").validate();... I'll read the documentation

Answer (score 1):

This might be something like what you're looking for...

```
$(".data-1 :input").each( function() {
   var val = $.trim($(this).val());
   if ( val != '' ) {
       // do stuff here...
   }
});
```

Comment: It works fine for the text inputs, I'll give it a try with the checkboxes and radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
$(".data-1 :input").val();
```

...will give you the value of the *first* input element within the *first* ".data-1" `div`. It won't give you all of them.

To get the values of all of them, you can use `map` (usually followed by `get`):

```
var values = $(".data-1 :input").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

That will give you an array of the values.

The array created above will include blank values. If you want to omit empty values, just return `undefined` from the iterator function for them and they'll be left out:

```
var values = $(".data-1 :input").map(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    return val ? val : undefined;
}).get();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".data-1 :input:not(:empty)").each(function()
{
// Iterating the not empty inputs
// $(this).val() contains the value of the current input
});
```

Comment: No, [`:empty`](http://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/) checks for *no child elements*, not blank values. `input` elements are empty by definition (`select` and `textbox` may not be, but either way it's about having a non-blank value, not having child elements).